# Не отправляются письма через SMTP и Flask-Mail

Tags: python, flask, smtp, smtplib

Не получается отправлять письма через smtp яндекса через Flask-Mail
конфиг следующий:

```
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USE_TLS = True
MAIL_DEBUG = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'почта для бизнеса с доменом через @'
MAIl_PASSWORD = 'пароль для приложений'
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = MAIL_USERNAME
```

Выдает постоянно следующую ошибку: `503, b'5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yandex не разрешает соединения без SSL [Документация](https://yandex.com/support/mail/mail-clients.html). Выставьте `MAIL_USE_SSL=True`, уберите `MAIL_USE_TLS=True`  и используйте порт `465`